# Infinite series bounded by another infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Is there a way to prove that $$\left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_{i}|^{p} \right)^{m/p} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_{i}|^{m}$$

for $0 < m < p$? I'm not sure where to start and would appreciate any help!

As a side question, I was wondering if $\lim_{p \to \infty} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_{i}|^{p} \right)^{m/p}$ exists. I have a hunch it does, but I'd like to prove it. Is it possible to prove it converges by using the Monotone Convergence Theorem, since we've shown it is bounded already? How would we prove it is monotone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise both sides to $\frac{p}{m}$ power and get  $\sum\limits_1^\infty|x_i|^p\le (\sum\limits_1^\infty|x_i|^m)^{p/m}=\sum\limits_1^\infty|x_i|^p+$(non-negative) cross terms.

Comment: Your argument assumes $p/m$ is an integer. How would your argument work if $m=2,p=\pi$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling that's a good point. Is there a better way to go about proving this?

Comment: For a two term sum assuming $a\gt b\gt 0$, and $c\gt 1$.  Then $(a+b)^c=$    $a^c(1+r)^c\ge a^c(1+cr^{c-1}+...\ge a^c(1+r^c+...=$    $a^c+b^c+...\ge a^c+b^c$ where $r=b/a$.  This can be generalized to arbitrary sum.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Does this need the assumption that $x_i$ is a decreasing sequence? Is that enough to prove that $\left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_{i}|^{p} \right)^{m/p}$ is decreasing? Then we know it is bounded and it is monotone, so it must converge as well.

Comment: Use math. induction.  Let $S=\sum\limits_1^n a_k$  Then $(\sum\limits_1^{n+1} a_k)^c=(S+a_{n+1})^c=S^c(1+a_{n+1}/S)^c$$\ge S^c(1+(a_{n+1}/S)^c)=S^c+a_{n+1}^c$$\ge \sum\limits_1^{n +1}a_k^c$, by induction (assume true for $n$). Comment:  $a_{n+1}\lt S$, else rearrange.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thanks for your comment! I'm still struggling to use this to show that the limit exists though.

Comment: Induction shows it holds for all $n$.  Convergence has to assumed.  For example $p=2$ and $m=1$ with $x_k=\frac{1}{k}$ will converge for $p$ but not for $m$.

Comment: Thank you! I see that now.